# How to remove item from an array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat, array-splice

I have a dropdown where items are populated from $scope.role. Now I need to remove the values from $scope.role once the value is added or selected in dropdown. I did splice(index,1) which actually delete the first element only. Need assistance.

```
$scope.role = ['Actor', 'Director/ Asst. director', 'Lyricist',
 'Music director/ Asst. director', 'Singer', 'Standup Comedian', 'Model',
 'Cinematographer', 'Photographer', 'Script Writer', 'Choreographer',
 'Editor/ Promo editor', 'Costume designer', 'Art director', 'Stunt artist',
 'Voice-over artist', 'Graphic Designer', 'Screenplay', 'Dialogue', 
'Back ground music'];
```

Html:

```
 <div class="row newRow">
  <div class="form-group fields col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
    <label>ROLE *</label>
    <select name="role" class="form-control1 drop2" required ng-model="model.role" placeholder="select">
      <option value='' disabled selected>Select</option>
      <option ng-repeat="item in role track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
    <button ng-click="AddRole()">Click to Add Role</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.multiRoles = [];
$scope.role == $scope.dummy;
$scope.rolesAdded = false;

$scope.AddRole = function(index) {
  debugger;
  if ($scope.model.role !== undefined) {
    $scope.multiRoles.push($scope.model.role);
    $scope.role.splice(index, 1);
    console.log($scope.role);
  }
};
```

Comment: what do you mean by `I did splice(index,1) which actually delete the first element only`? do you have duplicate keys in your array? If yes, you wanna delete all the duplicated keys?

Comment: @NicoletaWilskon you are passing nothing to AddRole. index is undefined. So it deletes the first element only.

Comment: What I suppose to do for that

Comment: Yes i have duplicate in array multirole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two ways 1) As suggested by @nikjohn by sending your $index of dropdown in `ng-click = "AddRole($index)"` and then splice or else

2) You can find the index of the selected option by using the `ng-model` binded to the dropdown.

```
     $scope.AddRole = function(){
          debugger;
          if($scope.model.role !== undefined ){
          $scope.multiRoles.push($scope.model.role);
          var index = $scope.role.indexOf($scope.model.role); //just find the right index which is the selected option in dropdown.
          $scope.role.splice(index,1);
                console.log($scope.role);
            }
        };
```

Comment: Thank you.Its really helpful.var index = $scope.role.indexOf($scope.model.role);  this is were i lacked .

Comment: Glad it helped you ! Happy coding mate :) One more to suggest use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` that has many capabilities in case of drop down.

Comment: @NicoletaWilskon can you accept this as an answer  mate ?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, pass `$index` to the `AddRole`. Otherwise, the function does not know what `$index` is, and also **include the button within the ng-repeat**:

```
<select name="role" 
  class="form-control1 drop2" required  
  ng-model="model.role" placeholder="select">
    <option value='' disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in role track by $index" value="{{item}}">   {{item}}
        <button ng-click = "AddRole($index)">Click to Add Role</button>
    </option>
</select>
```

In your Controller, there's an extra `=` that I've highlighted in my comment:

```
$scope.multiRoles = [];
$scope.role == $scope.dummy; // Why a `==` here? This should be a `=`
$scope.rolesAdded = false;        
$scope.AddRole = function(index){
   debugger;
   if($scope.model.role.length){ // Cleaner method to verify that the array is non-empty
   $scope.multiRoles.push($scope.model.role);
   $scope.role.splice(index,1);
     console.log($scope.role);
   }
 };
```

May I also suggest that you use Angular's select implementation with `ng-options` because:

> #### Choosing between ngRepeat and ngOptions
>
> In many cases, ngRepeat can be used on  elements instead of ngOptions to achieve a similar result. However, ngOptions provides some benefits:

- more flexibility in how the `<select>`'s model is assigned via the select as part of the comprehension expression
- reduced memory consumption by not creating a new scope for each repeated instance
- increased render speed by creating the options in a documentFragment instead of individually
- Specifically, select with repeated options slows down significantly starting at 2000 options in Chrome and Internet Explorer / Edge.

Comment: Hi ,even this delete the first array element .

Comment: You also need to put the button within your `ng-repeat`. Updated the answer

Comment: nickjohn. $index is not proper solution in this case

Comment: @AnilKumarRam Why's that?

Comment: @nikjohn you solution is also right mate but in many cases you dont want to repeat you button element in ng-repeat as you display it only once so that's this solution is not that feasible.